# python pywinauto selecting forefront window but now showing all element

Tags: python, user-interface, pywinauto

I'm selecting a newly open dialog after clicking on a button on the main page, but it's not showing all elements.

My code:

```
BIG_IP_APP_NAME = 'BIG-IP Edge Client™'

app = Desktop(backend='win32')

window = app[BIG_IP_APP_NAME].set_focus()
time.sleep(2)
window.maximize()
print(window.children())
```

it seems my code is only selecting the bottom dialog as shown in picture!
[window dialogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XcDC.png)

my main goal is to click on "Logon" button.

Inspection page [ispection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu30D.png)

when printing children of the window (it seems the only button is cancel):
[window children] https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycDxJ.png

Comment: Please post the code as a text, not an image.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Inspect.exe`, you must use `app = Desktop(backend='uia')`. It will provide different hierarchy than "win32" backend, it is expected behavior.

For example, "uia" window may be a child of initial window, while in "win32" each window is a child of `Desktop` object (top level window).

Comment: but when I'm using app = 'Desktop(backend='uia')' I'm not seeing the window, because this window is like a sub-window of the main window

Comment: What's the problem to use something like `app[BIG_IP_APP_NAME]["Child window name"].dump_tree()`? I'd recommend to fully read [this guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).